Why Does Every Member of the Ensemble Perform Work Equal to the Change in Free Energy During a Quasiequilibrium Process?
I'm studying Jarzynski's 1997 paper on the Jarzynski Equality. In the second part of the proof (from equation (9) to equation (10) in the paper), Jarzynski considers the following process: considering a canonical ensemble, the macroparameters of the system are changed from A to B by performing work. Assuming this process is quasi-static, we have "$W = \Delta F$ for every member of the ensemble, in that limiting case."
I don't quite understand what is meant by "work for every member." As I understand it, work and free energy are statistical properties. How should I interpret Jarzynski's statement?
